# Kinetic energy at perihelion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion

How do you find the kinetic energy of an object (in orbit around the sun) at perihelion given it's eccentricity, the mass of the object and it's period?

Comment: This may help you to refine your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy (or answer it ;) )

Comment: @N4v4rZ3r0 What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: That's standard fare for any intermediate mechanics book, including engineering books. Is there a concept that you have encountered in your studies that you need help with?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few relationships that enabled me to find the planet's KE at perihelion in terms of the mass of the planet, the mass, $M$, of the sun, the period, $T$, and the eccentricity. I leave the rest of the work to you.

(a) Kepler's second law can be written as
$$\tfrac12 r^2 \frac {d\theta}{dt} =\frac{\pi ab}{T}$$
$a$ and $b$ are the semi major and semi-minor axis lengths, so $\pi ab$ is the area of the ellipse. $\frac {d\theta}{dt}$ is the angular velocity of the planet about the Sun. At perihelion the left hand side of the equation can be written neatly in terms of $r_{min}$ and $v_{max}$.

(b) A neat geometrical relationship involving the semi-minor axis length, $b$, is
$$b^2 = r_{max}r_{min}.$$
(c) A useful geometrical relationship involving eccentricity, $\epsilon$, is
$$\epsilon= \frac {a-r_{min}}{a}.$$
(d) The Newtonian take on Kepler's Third law can be written as
$$\frac{GM}{a^3} = \frac{4\pi^2}{T^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a homework question, I will only give some useful relations.

- from [definition of eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#First_law) ($\epsilon$):
  $$r_\text{min}=a(1-\epsilon) \\ r_\text{max}=a(1+\epsilon)$$
- the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation)
  $$v^2=GM\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$
- [Kepler's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law)
  $$\frac{a^3}{T^2}=\frac{GM}{4\pi^2}$$

From all these you should be able to eliminate $a$
and calculate the kinetic energy at perihelion in terms of $m$, $\epsilon$ and $T$.